# make redis server ignore Ctrl+C when launched from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redis

I want to use shell script to launch Redis server and then monitor a log file:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/redis/src/redis-server &
tail -f /path/to/log/logfile.log
```

If I run this script and press Ctrl+C from the terminal, the `tail -f` terminated, which is what I want, however the Redis also detected SIGINT and exited.

I tried to write the script like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 trap '' INT TSTP
 ~/redis/src/redis-server &
 tail -f ./script1
```

This time things go even worse, the `tail -f` refused to terminate while Redis **still** detected SIGINT and exited.

It seems that there is some problems specific to Redis regarding ignoring signals.

My goal is to make `tail -f` responds to Ctrl+C while making Redis ignore this signal.

Please anyone tell me whether this can be achieved and if so, give me some advice?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the behavior you are seeing.  What OS are you on?  What version of Redis?

Comment: @Jack, I am using Ubuntu 12.04.5 and Redis 3.2.9

Comment: A workaround may be to run it as `setsid  ~/redis/src/redis-server &`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Excellent solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redis-server` catches `SIGINT` (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>), even if `SIGINT` was being ignored. This is an unusual choice; most software will check and won't catch `SIGINT` if it's already being ignored.

When it receives `SIGINT`, it saves the database and shuts down.

If you [start it as a service](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart#installing-redis-more-properly), it won't be associated with any terminal at all, and won't see any <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> you type.

If you start it as a background job in an interactive shell:

```
$ /path/to/redis/src/redis-server &
```

your shell will put it into a process group that is different from the terminal's process group, and typing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> won't affect it. (If you bring it to the foreground with `fg`, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> will send `SIGINT` to the program).

But, when you run a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/redis/src/redis-server &
tail -f /path/to/log/logfile.log
```

the shell that runs the script will be non-interactive, and any program that it starts in the background (with `&`) will be in the same process group as the shell. So if you run that shell script in the foreground, typing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> will send `SIGINT` to the shell, to `redis-server`, and to `tail`.

To prevent <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> from sending `SIGINT` to `redis-server` in a case like this, you need to either put `redis-server` in its own process group or disassociate it from your terminal. You can do this with [`setsid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsid.html), which does both:

```
#!/bin/bash
setsid /path/to/redis/src/redis-server &
tail -f /path/to/log/logfile.log
```